# failure to login: for principal: jztwk javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I use CDH 6.3.2

I sumbit oozie job with spark,but I get a error

```
..................................
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:141)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: for principal: jztwk javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getUGIFromTicketCache(UserGroupInformation.java:649)
    ........................................

    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:93)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:60)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
```

but I can run spark-submit ..........

I can run spark-shell

in oozie hive,shell work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is bug in spark,you need update spark 3.0 or CDH 6.3.3

Answer (score 0):

my workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app  name="Spark-example2" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">  
    <start to="SparkOozieAction1"/>  
    <action name="SparkOozieAction1">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">  
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>  
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>         
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>Spark Example1</name>
            <class>App</class>            
            <jar>JztCloudAnalyse.jar</jar> 
            <spark-opts>--jars ${nameNode}/sparklib/*.jar  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 </spark-opts> 
            <arg>-r 10.3.87.31:7000,10.3.87.31:7001,10.3.87.32:7002,10.3.87.32:7003,10.3.87.36:7004,10.3.87.36:7005 -d 0 -k 22 -w http://10.3.87.49:8082/SendMsgApi.ashx -n JZTanalyse10_102 -h JZTanalyse -o jjj</arg>            
           <file>/user/jztwk/JztCloudAnalyse.jar#JztCloudAnalyse.jar</file>
        </spark> 
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>    
    </action>  
    <kill name="kill">  
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>  
    </kill>  
    <end name="end"/>  
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

my job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://nameservice1
dryrun=False
jobTracker=bigdser3:8032
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=True　　
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/jztwk
security_enabled=True
```